# New at haskel having trouble with String -> Double in list

Tags: haskell

I'm having fun with this new language except sometimes its difficult to troubleshoot.

Here is what my prof wants, he wants me to accept numbers from the user and calculate a running avg.

Now so far this is what I have except my basic prog gives error for some type error.

I'm a Student in Comp Sci, and this is an assignment question which I am trying to do on my own.

```
   module Main (listM, main) where

   import System.IO  
   import Data.List

   listM = [1, 2, 3]


    main = do

     average listM = realToFrac (sum listM) / genericLength listM   

     putStrLn (show(listM))
```

Now i have this error, driving me crazy ... :S
  Q1.hs:12:18: parse error on input `='

Comment: Imports must be done *before* definitions. Also check your identation, it's relevant.

Comment: I edited to change the indentation back to what it was originally, since it's relevant to the error (and several of the answers don't make sense once the indentation is "corrected")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good to hear that you are having fun learning Haskell!

As far as your assignment is concerned: you're not doing bad at all. I'd say: you're almost there.

As Dwilson explained in his excellent answer, the reason that the compiler rejects your program is that your definition of `listM` was put before the imports. In a Haskell module, you always start with the module header (sometimes preceded by some pragmas) and a list of imports and then the definitions of your functions:

```
module Main (main) where

import System.IO
import Data.List

...
```

Now, you mention that the compiler (or perhaps the interpreter) rejects your program due to a "type error". But what you are getting is actually a "parse error". It won't hurt to understand the difference between the two:

- When the compiler processes your program it first checks whether your
  program is syntactically correct. If it isn't, it will trow a parse
  error at you.
- Then, it checks whether you use your functions in a consistent matter,
  i.e., it checks whether the types are correct. If they are not, you
  will be confronted with a type error.

Generally, the first class of errors is dealt with easily: the compiler almost always points you to the spot in your program were you made a mistake or a typo (in your case: the first import statement). The second class of errors is sometimes more tricky to deal with—but becoming a good Haskell programmer involves familiarise yourself with the type system and really understand what's going on there (rather than just trying out things until it more or less works...) No worries though: it's not half as hard as you may think.

Looking it your code, it strikes me that you define

```
average xs = realToFrac (sum listM) / genericLength listM
```

That is, that you define `average` to be a **function** that takes an argument `xs`, but that you're not using `xs` at the right-hand side of your definition. Is `xs` supposed to be the list that you are computing the average for? In your code, your function always computes the average of the fix list `listM`, no matter what list you supply as argument to `average`. Apart from that, your function is okay.

Now the only thing you will have to do is thing about how to prompt the user for input and how to build a list of numbers out of that input.

Good luck—and have fun! ;)

Comment: Hey thanks @dbhelix , i'm going to implement some changes and hopefully get back to you with a positive result ;) haskell is good but i really want to improve quick... it's interesting on the way it works :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as your input error goes it's because `import System.IO` is indented ahead of `import Data.List`. In Haskell indentation is important, although you can use curly braces and semicolons if you want to. Any line that is indented farther than a previous line counts as a continuation of that line, so ghc is interpreting your file as `listM = [1, 2, 3] import System.IO`.

Now, if that's the only thing you needed help on then have fun with Haskell! However if you need help with the structure you should clarify what you're looking for. You're description of what the professor wants and what you expect to happen do not match up. Specifically the professor says you should get numbers from the user which usually means you're going to be prompting them at the command line, however you say you want the program to sum the numbers in `listM` which is not inputted from the user. Which one is it?

**Edit**
Update to reflect the current status `parse error on '='`.

GHC's errors can be daunting at first, but I've found that they are actually a lot more helpful than other languages when you get used to them. Don't worry you'll get there! Now the thing this error is telling you is that GHC doesn't know what to do when it hits the `=`  on the line `average listM = realToFrac (sum listM) / genericLength listM`. This is because it's treating it as a continuation of the `main = do` line, and in a `do` block all binding with `=` must be done with a `let` statement, like so: `let average listM = realToFrac (sum listM) / genericLength listM`. Now this probably isn't what you want, because then your function `average` will only be available in the do block! What you should do is define `average` outside of the `do` block and then call it at some point inside the `do` block.

A couple pointers:

- Indentation is **very** important. Haskell determines scope, line endings, etc. by indentation.
- `ParseError`s usually mean there's something wrong syntactically with your code. The first thing you should do when you encounter one is check for indentation, then check for missing parentheses, brackets, etc.
- In a do block:

  - `let` and `=` are used to bind things that are *not* monadic, e.g. `let x = length "foobar"`
  - The `<-` operator is used to bind things that are monadic, e.g. `x <- getChar`

Comment: Well im breaking th problem in pieces the way i see it is, that if i can create a list of numbers and then print out the avg to the screen i should easily be able to prompt the user for number later . However i tried and now the import stmts are not indented are at the same level "i'll edit my code above to show what i have on my screen" however now i have this new found error 

Q1.hs:12:18: parse error on input `='